# Cypher: How to get all possible variable-length chains and output concatenated string of node properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First time using neo4j. This is what my graph looks like.
[image: Graph DB]

The central node is of type `Job`, and the child nodes are of type `Word`. Each Word node has property `word` (i.e. `Word.word`), which is equivalent to the node labels such as "react", "php" etc. in the attached image.

What I am trying to do is for each chain of child nodes, generate a concatenated string of Word.word property values. For example, for the attached graph, I want to return something like:

```
[ "php", "react js", "javascript", "full stack development", "multithreaded load-balancing reactor engine"]
```

My current brute force approach looks like this:

```
match (webdev:Job {name:"Web Developer"}),
(webdev)-[a00:Appearance]->(w1:Word),
(w1)-[a01:Appearance]->(w2:Word),
(w2)-[a02:Appearance]->(w3:Word)
return w1.word + ' ' + w2.word + ' ' + w3.word as name

union

match (webdev:Job {name:"Web Developer"}),
(webdev)-[a00:Appearance]->(w1:Word),
(w1)-[a01:Appearance]->(w2:Word)
where not ((w2)-->())
return w1.word + ' ' + w2.word as name

union

match (webdev:Job {name:"Web Developer"}),
(webdev)-[a00:Appearance]->(w1:Word)
where not ((w1)-->())
return w1.word as name
```

which produces the output:

```
["multithreaded load-balancing reactor","full stack development","react js","php","javascript"]
```

This works for chains of length <= 3, but obviously it fails for length > 3. Notice how the string "multithreaded load-balancing reactor" should be "multithreaded load-balancing reactor engine".

**My question is: how to I generalize this for all chains of variable length?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [variable length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern:

```
MATCH p = (:Job {name:"Web Developer"})-[:Appearance*]->(leaf)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:Appearance]->()
RETURN REDUCE(s = NODES(p)[1].word, w IN NODES(p)[2..] | s + ' ' + w.word) AS name
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Thanks @cybersam :)